# python sshtunnel port forward not worked

Tags: python, paramiko

```
  my-pc                 ssh-server         another-app-server
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 127.0.0.1:12345 ----> x.x.x.x:22  ---->  y.y.y.y:8080 [only accessed by ssh-server]
```

Actually i want do this as above and my-pc run windows10

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from time import sleep
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (x.x.x.x),
    ssh_username=MY_SSH_SERVER_USER,
    ssh_private_key=MY_KEY_PATH,
    remote_bind_address=(y.y.y.y, 8080),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 12345)
) as server :
server.start()
sleep(60)
```

when i run it's always tell me `ERROR   | Problem setting SSH Forwarder up: Couldn't open tunnel 127.0.0.1:12345 <> y.y.y.y:8080 might be in use or destination not reachable  ....`, and i use this following code it's worked.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from time import sleep
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (x.x.x.x),
    ssh_username=MY_SSH_SERVER_USER,
    ssh_private_key=MY_KEY_PATH,
    remote_bind_address=(y.y.y.y, 8080),
) as server :
server.start()
print(server.local_bind_port) # RANDOM PORT !! I HATE RANDOM!!
sleep(60)
```

but i just want bind 12345 as the port (it's now be used, i am sure), how can i do ????

Comment: What is the complete error messsage?

Comment: Use `netstat` to check whether something else is already using port 12345.

Comment: never used！  i am sure , i check it ever and ever again

Comment: Well if it works with random port, then there's obviously something wrong with the `127.0.0.1:12345`. Either the IP (unlikely) or the port (more likely). Did you try your code with the "random port", but explicitly specified instead of the 12345?

Comment: I change another port-mumber it's worked !! even i never seen 12345 be used ... just i don't know why (not within the scope of this discussion , i'll find out )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check if port 12345 is already used do :

```
netstat -aof | findstr :12345
```

if the command returned any process that means that it's in use.
you can either way change to other ports like `5000`,`1080`,`3000` etc

Comment: there is also another chance that you have run the script second time without stopping the first one (closing cmd doesn't stop it ) this will also give used port error

Comment: I'am very  sorry !!  I change another port-mumber it's worked !! even i never seen 12345 be  used  ... just i don't know why (not within the scope of this discussion , i'll  find out ).

Comment: no worries , about the port  12345 could be reserved port for some app in windows or by windows itself (just a guess ).